# PLSQL Count and Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Currently trying to create a PL/SQL procedure. I am a complete noob at PL/SQL, as you can tell!

We have had to create a table using SQL, and we are looking to automatically update the table with a procedure. If the customer has requested more than 4 jobs, we are looking to input their details into this table as a frequent customer.

I currently have at the moment:

```
 CREATE TABLE PublisherDetails
 (PublisherName VARCHAR2 (40),
 City VARCHAR2 (20) ,
 PhoneNo NUMBER (11),
 jobNo NUMBER (10),
  startDate DATE,
 completionDate DATE)
 ;

 SELECT Publisher.Name AS PublisherName,
 Publisher.City, Publisher.PhoneNo,
 COUNT (*) AS PublisherJobCount
 FROM Publisher
 INNER JOIN PrintJob
 ON Publisher.Name = PrintJob.PublisherName
 GROUP BY Publisher.Name, Publisher.City, Publisher.PhoneNo;

Create or replace procedure Task3
IS CountPublisherJobs NUMBER;
DECLARE No_data_Found EXCEPTION
BEGIN
SELECT count(*) INTO CountPublisherJobs 
OPEN Task3;
LOOP
IF PublisherJobCount < 3
THEN INSERT INTO PublisherDetails (PublisherName, City, PhoneNo)
FROM Publisher
WHERE PublisherName = publisher.name
Else
            Insert Into PublisherDetails (JobNo, StartDate, CompletionDate )
            SELECT jobNo, startDate, completionDate
            FROM PrintJob
            Where PublisherName = publishers.name
  FETCH Task3 INTO PublisherDetails, publishername, city, phoneNo;
  EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;  

    INSERT INTO temp VALUES (PublisherName, City, PhoneNo, JobNo, StartDate, CompletionDate);
END IF;
    COMMIT;
END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Sorry no data found');
    END;
    /
```

Its churning up errors and I am not sure why. Any help as always is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is no real need to post all your code, just the relevant part. Right now it looks like you asking someone to help you solving a problem, but to write the whole code for you. This is not SO is for. Try to show your actual efforts to separate the problem from the whole context. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, I only copied the actual code part as people were saying it wasnt easy to understand without the context.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things incorrect with the syntax of your procedure.

The basic format for a stored procedure is

```
Create {Or Replace} Procedure PROCEDURE_NAME {(i_param IN datatype)}
Is
  <<Declaration Section>>
Begin
  <<code section>>
Exception
  <<Exceptions>>
End PROCEDURE_NAME;
```

From what you have described above, you want to insert a record into a table, when a condition is met in another table.

To accomplish this, I would need to see the underlying data structure, what you have provided doesn't show the tables the data is currently in (is there a JOB table for instance? a Customer table?).

The `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception does not need to be declared, it is an Oracle exception

Your `Select Count(*) Into CountJobs` is missing a `From TABLE`, and any predicates you want to add, although I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with this.

You are attempting to open a cursor on the procedure name. You have not defined a cursor with the name Task3

You have not declared the CountPublisherJobs variable

I would suggest perhaps revisiting the basic structure for a stored procedure.

**Edit**

Based on your response, you could achieve the result using the following:

```
Create Or Replace Procedure addFrequentPublisher
Is
  Cursor frequentPublishers Is 
    Select  PUBLISHER_ID
    From    JOB
    Group By 
            PUBLISHER_ID
    Having  Count(*) >= 4;
Begin
 For i In frequentPublishers
 Loop
   Insert Into FREQUENT_CUSTOMER ...
 End Loop;
End;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

The table has been created seperately. 

There is a publisher table and a job table in the schema.

Comment: @user93etc., your code is impossible to correct. Read carefully what mmartin has said. We lack A LOT of information to assist you do that task. I tried to write a procedure in order to suggest *something*, but - as I said - there are just too many unknown things that make it impossible. You should start from scratch, step by step, testing frequently, because this code is simply rubbish (pardon my French), regardless you being a PL/SQL newbie.

Comment: @user9364289 please see my edit. The code will achieve what you want, however, I have made **A LOT** of assumptions on the underlying data. I hope that this helps, however, I would recommend that you up a lot more on the structure of a PL/SQL code block

Comment: Thank you Martin :)

I have amended it to the above and the count is now working. I am aware its "rubbish" but I am pretty sure that noone as born an expert and need to start somewhere.